# Two factors authentication

Tags: asp.net-identity

I'm still discovering asp.net identity and I'm wondering if it's possible to use the double factor authentication mechanism with a token instead of a cookie.

I have tried different things but cannot see if it's possible.

Does anyone has an idea?

thanks

Comment: Are you using the beta 2.0.0?  Two factor authentication was added in this release [ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/adding-two-factor-authentication-to-an-application-using-asp-net-identity.aspx ]. What have you tried so far that is not working?

Comment: I'm using the 2.0.0 version. I have no problem using it with cookies. However, I'm not able to use it without cookies. I did not find how to configure it (or if it's possible).

Comment: Still not clear on what you are trying to do.  Show some code on what you have attempted to do and provide more details on what exactly is failing.

Comment: All examples I found show the two-factor authentication with cookie. E.g., there is a cookie added in the response after the POST with the login and password. And there is a cookie added once the user is authenticated. (So two cookies in total).

But I would like to use tokens only. And for the moment I don't know which piece of code I'm supposed to replace in the examples I have found.